# Do Flutter apps work on Android Go with 1GB Ram?

Tags: android, flutter, android-go

Im considering creating a simple signature pad app in flutter and was considering getting one of the cheap <$100 tablets running Android Go with 1GB Ram like Lenovo M7 to use for that, cheaper and better value I believe than buying an actual signature pad.

Will flutter apps run on Android Go, and is 1GB memory enough for basic functionality?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Flutter is incredibly lightweight and has been proven to not be much more taxing than native if any more at all. How flutter works is it draws all the widgets on the screen. So flutter itself is relatively lightweight. So as long as you don't overdo with animations or classes in memory I don't see why not.

I recommend this article if you need more in-depth knowledge : https://medium.com/swlh/flutter-vs-native-vs-react-native-examining-performance-31338f081980